# How to make Skype Mobile for Android permit PC-to-PC calling?

Tags: wi-fi, skype

I purchased a Samsung Galaxy Tab from Verizon Wireless without a contract, so no 3G support -- only WiFi. I went to Skype.com/m and installed Skype Mobile for Android. After installation, it lets me only do Skype Chat. If I try to do a Skype Call (PC-to-PC calling), it won't let me -- the call just dies. Does anyone know how to make it permit PC-to-PC calling, even though this "PC" is actually a Galaxy Tab on my end?

I mean, Android is built on Linux, and my Linux PC has a version of Skype that permits PC-to-PC calling, so I don't understand what the issue is here for Skype.com on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skype today released Skype 1.0.2, and mayor change is support for Samsung Galaxy S. Maybe this will affect your phone too. Update and see

Comment: New development! You may be the guy I check off with the answer. Somehow I have triggered my Skype (don't know how) to support calling again using the new Skype. Turns out that 1.0.2 is actually 1.0.0.659, I think, because people have speculated this and no one has countered that. Anyway, I found that if I go into my Galaxy Tab settings (where I am wifi only) and change Settings > Mobile Network > Data Roaming, and turn it off, and then switch Settings > Mobile Network > System Select to "Home only" -- my Skype calling now works reliably at least for now, under multiple attempts.

Answer (score 3):

What's odd is that there seem to be three different Skype apps for Android, but most people can only see one or the other available.

There's [Skype](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.skype.raider/) available in the Market and currently at v1.0.0.659. This lists:

> Skype-to-Skype calls over 3G or WiFi
>
> Data plan or WiFi connection required
>   (calling in U.S - WiFi only)

Then there's [Skype Mobile for Verizon](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.skype.android.verizon/), which I think is at v1.5.0.16. This one says this but doesn't mention WiFi in its description currently:

> Unlimited Skype-to-Skype calls and Instant messaging without using your plan minutes

Finally the **3** network in the UK have a special version of the Skype app where you're never charged for Skype calls over their network, [get that here](http://www.three.co.uk/_popup/Skype) (only works if you're on the 3 network).

It looks like the Market must be doing a check on your country (or maybe which phone network your device is locked to?) to decide which to give you, and so which restrictions to apply to you.

It looks like your device is only offering you Skype Mobile, and not Skype.

Gotta love how the phone companies are desperately trying to keep themselves relevant in the face of customers who really would rather do things another way!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a Galaxy S/Tab specific issue.  I and many others cannot get Skype to work on our Galaxy S devices, and the Tab is very similar.